# Is There A Simple Powershell Command to tell if COM+ Application is Paused?

Tags: powershell, com+

This Powershell code will start/shutdown a COM+, I'm thinking.

```
$comAdmin= New-Object -com ("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog.1")

$comAdmin.ShutdownApplication("pkgAdap2")

 $comAdmin.StartApplication("pkgAdap2")
```

Powershell doesn't complain. But how do I look and see if the Application is shutdown/started? I can see it in the Component Services window, but not sure how to tell if it is running.

Is there an easy way to use Powershell to tell me this?
I have found that there is a COMAdminCatalogObject called "IsPaused" which returns a true or false. However, I don't know how to reference it. All examples and solutions I have found are multiline loops through all Applications in the Component Services.
I was thinking something like this would work:

```
$comAdmin.IsPaused("pkgAdap2")
```

Answer (score 3):

**COM List**

```
$comAdmin = New-Object -com ("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog.1")
$applications = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications") 
$applications.Populate() 

foreach ($application in $applications)
{

    $components = $applications.GetCollection("Components",$application.key)
    $components.Populate()
    foreach ($component in $components)
    {

        $dllName = $component.Value("DLL")
        $componentName = $component.Name

        "Component Name:$componentName"
        "DllName: $dllName`n"
    }
}
```

You can **Start** or **Stop** Using:

```
$comAdmin.StartApplication("appName")
$comAdmin.ShutdownApplication("appName")
```

For Installation :

**Refer to**: [Microsoft Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681806(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
$comAdmin.InstallApplication("fileName")
```

For **Shutting down all COM**:

```
$sb = {
    $admin = New-Object -Com ("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog")
    $apps = $admin.GetCollection("Applications")
    $apps.Populate()
    $apps | % {
        $component = $apps.GetCollection("Components", $_.Key)
        $component.Populate()
        $component | % {
            $admin.ShutdownApplication("$_.Name")
        } 
    }
}

$servers | % {Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock $sb}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

There:

```
$catalog = New-Object -ComObject "COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog"

$appCollection = $catalog.GetCollection("Applications")
$appCollection.Populate()
$appList = @{}
$appCollection | ForEach-Object {
  $appList.Add($_.Value("ID"), $_.Name)
}

$appInstances = $catalog.GetCollection("ApplicationInstances")
$appInstances.Populate()
$appInstanceList = @{}
$appInstances | ForEach-Object {
  $appValue = $_.Value("Application")
  $appInstanceList.Add($appValue, $appList[$appValue])
}

$appList.Keys | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    "Name"    = $appList[$_]
    "ID"      = $_
    "Running" = $appInstanceList.ContainsKey($_)
  }
}
```